# Windows 7 Not Recognizing Camera Nor iPhone as Camera

Tags: windows-7, iphone, usb, camera

I've been struggling with this one for a few days.  I've recently upgraded an older computer to Windows 7 Home Premium.  Neither my digital camera (A Canon SD1200IS) nor iPhone are ever detected as cameras, nor ever show up as accessable in Explorer.

With the Canon camera, no driver is required.  It's supposed to work with the default Windows 7 drivers.  However, in the Control Panel's Device Manager, I'm always seeing a yellow icon next to the "Canon Digital Camera" device.  I've uninstalled the device and let Windows attempt to reinstall, but it can never find a driver to install.

With the iPhone, it's very similar.  One big difference, though, is that iTunes can see the iPhone and back it up, etc.  However, again when I go to the Device Manager, there's a yellow icon next to the iPhone.  I've uninstalled iTunes, reinstalled, rebooted, deleted drivers, and let Window try to reinstall the driver, but it can never find the driver.

So there seems to be some correlation that my machine can't detect cameras properly, and that it might be even a lower-level type of driver I'm struggling with.   I know that USB however, does work, because I have have an external drive hooked into the machine.

I've gone through the web and tried two hours worth of fixes, without success.  I feel like if I can get the Canon camera detected, then the iPhone will be on it's way to being fixed too.

BTW, I couldn't really find anything of use in the Event viewer.

Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: I do not believe that the iPhone can be used a camera for the PC. I believe you can only pull files off of it.

Comment: Was it a clean Install of Windows 7? Are you connecting them using a usb hub? or directly to a usb port on the PC?

Comment: Windows 7 has Service Pack 1 available. Did u check to make sure thatbwas part of the original dsc? SP1 does not get installed as annupdate vai Windows updatw. Go to syatem properties to see if its installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was caused by the laptop having the N version of Windows. This does not contain Windows media player, and some important drivers that come with it. Many devices need these drivers to connect.

The solution is to install the Windows 7 media feature pack. I shall not provide a link as it will not work when this answer gets too old, but googling "Windows 7 Media feature pack" should give you plenty of results.